# Add multiple rows google-spreadsheet npm

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I am using this npm google-spreadsheet to manipulate the google spreadsheets but I don't found any method to add multiple rows at once like Google sheet Api is already providing.

I have already used .addRow() method but to add multiple rows I need to run a loop which is inefficient. Is anyone here who faced similar problem and solve it using this npm only.

Answer (score 1):

How about just getting the rows and editing them and doing bulk save.

```
function workingWithCells(step) {
    sheet.getCells({
      'min-row': 1,
      'max-row': 5,
      'return-empty': true
    }, function(err, cells) {
      var cell = cells[0];
      console.log('Cell R'+cell.row+'C'+cell.col+' = '+cell.value);

      // cells have a value, numericValue, and formula
      cell.value == '1'
      cell.numericValue == 1;
      cell.formula == '=ROW()';

      // updating `value` is "smart" and generally handles things for you
      cell.value = 123;
      cell.value = '=A1+B2'
      cell.save(); //async

      // bulk updates make it easy to update many cells at once
      cells[0].value = 1;
      cells[1].value = 2;
      cells[2].formula = '=A1+B1';
      sheet.bulkUpdateCells(cells); //async

      step();
    });
  },
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-spreadsheet

Does this works for you.

Comment: Thanks! I had used this and found a GitHub issue with the memory.

Answer (score 1):

Batch clear:

```
const sheet = doc.sheetsByTitle['SheetName']
await sheet.clear('A2:B')
```

Batch insert:

```
const rows = []
for (const data of dataList) {
  rows.push({
    '#': data.num,
    Address: data.sku,
    Apartament: data.apartament,
  })
}

await sheet.addRows(rows)
```